# Prevent auto-fill on other fields on different step in multi-step form

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I have a multi-step form which keeps auto-filling fields on a different field on another step. How do I prevent it from doing that. This is an example:

```js
var current = 0;
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  tabs[current].style.display = "none";
  current = current + 1;
  showTab(current);
});
document.querySelector(".finish").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert("Finish");
});

function showTab() {
  tabs[current].style.display = "block";
}

showTab(current);
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="" action="" method="" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>First Name</h1>
            <label for="firstname" class="required">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
        </div>
        <button class="next" type="button">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Last Name</h1>
            <label for="lastname" class="required">Last Name</label>
            <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
        </div>
        <button class="finish" type="button">Finish</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, since there are no saved inputs on your storage on this form, it may not auto-fill as expected and is not completely reproducible. I still hope someone can help.

Comment: You need to apply ```autocomplete="off"``` on all the input fields

Comment: I need that for some inputs in the form